# apply css based on condition angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm alternating between two windows in angularjs using ng-click and ng-show :

```
<div ng-init="showTab2 = false">
            <a ng-click="showTab2 = true; showTab1 = false ">#Tab1 </a>
        </div>
 <div ng-init="showTab2 = true">
            <a ng-click="showTab1 = true; showTab2 = false">#Tab2</a>
        </div>
```

then with ng-show they appear

Could you please tell me how I can change the color of the tab selected ?

Thank you

Comment: This could help you http://codepen.io/DesignyourCode/pen/pECjv

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Comment: @User2 thank you for the detailed answer, it worked with ng-class but I couldn't use ng-switch because it creates an other $scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how your `ng-show` fits here but use `ng-class` to toggle css:

```
<a ng-class = "{'some-class': showTab1}" 
  ng-click="showTab1 = true; showTab2 = false">#Tab1</a>
```

Comment: it generates an error in the IDE "expression expected"

Answer (score 1):

Please check working example here:  [Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/QKb79N?p=preview)

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.showTab = 1; //If you want to select default tab
});
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <a ng-click="showTab = 1" ng-class="{'active': showTab == 1}">#Tab1 </a>
</div>
<div>
   <a ng-click="showTab = 2"  ng-class="{'active': showTab == 2}">#Tab2</a>
</div>

<div ng-switch="showTab">
    <span ng-switch-when="1">Tab1</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="2">Tab2</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.active {
   color: red;
 }
```